# C++ Builder 2007 message dialog problem

Tags: forms, c++builder, vcl

My message dilogs seem to disppear below the main form.
This only random. Most of the time it displays correctly on top, but some times disppear behind the main application form . What could be the reson?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look at the TForm::PopupMode, TForm::PopupParent, and TApplication::ModalPopupMode properties.  They were introduced specifically to fix Z-order problems that plaqued older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try using MyForm->ShowModal() instead of MyForm->Show()